# Android Developer Console 310 eroor

Tags: android

When I try to login to my Developer Console, I am getting the following error.

> Eroare 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): Au fost prea multe
>   redirecționări. ( Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): Too many
>   redirects.)

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Log out of your Google account in the browser and then try to login to developer console..

Comment: I tried that. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent an email to google and they helped me. If you have the same problem use this link https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?switch_back=1.